# Pandas - Extract value from column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with really long text in a column. I wanted to select all columns that contain ABC. I was able to do this using the following

```
 df[df['Column'].str.contains('ABC', na=False)]
```

What I want to do after that is extract all values from this field that contain the prefix and the next 5 letters.
S.So after finding a column, I would want to get ABC1234 or ABC7899.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` with a regular expression that says to capture any time it sees ABC with 5 following digits

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column':['ABC12345 is in this column', 'Not in this one CCD11111','Also in this one ABC99882']})
df['capture'] = df.Column.str.extract('(ABC\d{5})')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
                      Column   capture
0  ABC12345 is in this column  ABC12345
2   Also in this one ABC99882  ABC99882
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was really stuck on this.